# Sending DYMO xml label files directly to printer

Tags: windows, linux, command-line, printing

Is this possible on either lin or win? I've had this working with a Zebra printer by just using COPY/cat to send the EPL text file to the USB port, but no such luck with DYMO.

Under win I can print using DYMO software and use COPY to send to the printer, but the job just disappears out of the queue with no error and does not print.
Under lin I can print using lpr, however this prints the xml as plain text, which is no good.

Answer (score 0):

There is a command line tool with full source code written in C++ included in the samples section of the DYMO Label v.8 SDK.

It's called PrintLabel.exe and there's a Readme with usage info also.